# How to open/save and edit a .txt file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web

I have this project where I have to build a text editor, save the file as .txt  and also being able to open it and make some changes.

I'm trying to do this with Javascript and I'm having some trouble with this part, I already have the code for creating the file and open it but if I try to open a file and edit something I can't save to the same file, it creates another one.

I've done some research and I think is not possible to edit a file from Javascript. I'm open to any suggestion at this point on how to accomplish this.

I used the js library FileSaver and the File API from HTML5

```
function showFile() {
  const preview = document.getElementById('fuenteTextarea');
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  var textFile = /text.*/;

  if (file.type.match(textFile)) {
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      preview.innerHTML = event.target.result;
    };
  } else {
    preview.innerHTML = 'El archivo no es .txt';
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}


function saveStaticDataToFile() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById('fuenteTextarea').value;
  const blob = new Blob([userInput], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
  const namefile = document.getElementById('nombreArchivo').value;
  if (namefile === '') {
    alert('Recuerde el nombre del archivo');
  } else {
    saveAs(blob, `${namefile}.txt`);
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify a file clientside through javascript since this would be a great security issue.

Comment: And what would you recommend me to do in this case?

Comment: I can suggest you to use atoms electron framework for building desktop apps using html/JavaScript than trying to open a file directly like this.  https://electronjs.org/

Comment: handle it serverside?

Comment: @Cyclonecode Client-side JavaScript can modify files using the [File System Access API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/file-system-access).